# Can you tweak these codes for Userform : Make it small and efficient

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add dynamic userform controls like (labels, textboxes) on runtime, when userfrom activated with following order.

i want something like following

when userfrom activate, it needs to ask user number of fields, he /she want to insert ?
if user answer 7, then it need to add field in following order "**3 columns order**"

> Label1 textbox1      Label2 textbox1       Label3 textbox3
>
> Label4 textbox4      Label5 textbox5       Label6 textbox6
>
> Label7 textbox7      ........and so on based on number of field user
>   ask.

Request for enhancement in code :

[image]

i tried following codes:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Long

number = 10 'InputBox("Enter no of text-boxes and labels you wish to create at run-time", "Enter TextBox & Label Number")

Dim txtB1 As control

For i = 1 To 5

Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

With txtB1
.Name = "txtBox" & i
.Height = 20
.Width = 50
.Left = 70
.Top = 20 * i * 1
End With

Next i


For i = 6 To 10

Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

With txtB1
.Name = "txtBox" & i
.Height = 20
.Width = 50
.Left = 200
.Top = 20 * i - 100 * 1
End With

Next i


Dim lblL1 As control

For i = 1 To 5

Set lblL1 = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

With lblL1
.Caption = "Label" & i
.Name = "lbl" & i
.Height = 20
.Width = 50
.Left = 20
.Top = 20 * i * 1
End With

Next i


For i = 6 To 10

Set lblL1 = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

With lblL1
.Caption = "Label" & i
.Name = "lbl" & i
.Height = 20
.Width = 50
.Left = 150
.Top = 20 * i - 100 * 1
End With

Next i


Dim q As Long

For q = 1 To 5

Controls("lbl" & q) = Cells(1, q)

Next q


For q = 6 To 10

Controls("lbl" & q) = Cells(1, q)

Next q

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the issue with this code?

Comment: Hi @BrianMStafford thanks for your query. The issue is that i have to run almost 4 for loops to achieve the desired results. can't it be done with 1 or 2 nested for loops ? .also if you observe the codes, its like presently my loop to limited to 10 number only.  can i achieve it in 3 columns and unlimited rows based on no of fields user needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do an unlimited number of controls in 3 columns.  Instead of using nested For loops, try using a Do loop:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim nof As Integer
   nof = InputBox("Enter no of text-boxes and labels you wish to create at run-time", "Enter TextBox & Label Number")

   Dim nob As Integer
   nob = InputBox("Enter no of blanks you wish to create at run-time", "Enter Blanks")

   CreateFields nof, nob
End Sub

Private Sub CreateFields(ByVal NumberOfFields As Integer, _
                         ByVal NumberOfBlankFields As Integer)
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim Top As Single
   Dim Left As Single

   Top = 20
   Left = 20
   i = 1
   j = 1

   Do While i <= NumberOfFields + NumberOfBlankFields
      If i > NumberOfBlankFields Then
         CreateLabel "lbl" & j, "Label" & j, Top, Left
         CreateTextBox "txtBox" & j, "Text" & j, Top, Left + 30
         j = j + 1
      End If

      i = i + 1

      If i Mod 3 = 1 Then
         Top = Top + 50
         Left = 20
      Else
         Left = Left + 100
      End If
   Loop
End Sub

Private Sub CreateLabel(ByVal Name As String, _
                        ByVal Caption As String, _
                        ByVal Top As Single, _
                        ByVal Left As Single)
   With Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
      .Name = Name
      .Caption = Caption
      .Height = 20
      .Width = 50
      .Left = Left
      .Top = Top
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTextBox(ByVal Name As String, _
                          ByVal Text As String, _
                          ByVal Top As Single, _
                          ByVal Left As Single)
   With Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
      .Name = Name
      .Text = Text
      .Height = 20
      .Width = 50
      .Left = Left
      .Top = Top
   End With
End Sub
```

Of course, you can adjust the spacing of the controls as needed.

Comment: Codes are working great as per my expectations. i need little enhancement. Please Check question last lines, what i need to achieve. as i can't explain in comment box here.

Comment: @HeavyLoadCollection I added a prompt for number of fields.

Comment: yeah, its working great i am editing question for enhancement. please give me 10 minutes

Comment: Please check enhancement picture in question. can you get me something like that in picture. Thanks a lot

Comment: one last question with this thread. Can i change label captions like (A) (B) (C) and so on when labels control are added on runtime with above codes? Thanks

Comment: Also can i take textbox value  from worksheet row 1 (headings) ex. textbox1.value = worksheet("sheet1").range(:"A1") value  Textbox2 .value =  worksheet("sheet1").range(:"B1") .value and so on.with run time ?

Comment: Yes to your last 2 questions.  The second argument to CreateLabel and CreateTextbox are the Caption and Text respectively.  Change these arguments to whatever you need.  I updated the code for CreateTexbox to support this.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind reply and support. i ll  implement it. have a great day.

Comment: Can you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218183/how-to-paste-data-in-columns-and-rows-in-this-way  as it similar to this thread and you can better help.