# Paste Shapes group in column and rows with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have some shapes to print in columns and rows format based on the user-defined input Value. there are 3 main inputs based conditions:

1) No of starting label(shapes) to skip 
2) No of label(shapes) per Row 
3) No of Rows Per page

I have one datasheet which has data in column A (includes shapes) and No of copies to be printed in column B.

**Datasheet**

[image]

This thread is similar to [How to Paste Data in Columns and Rows in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218183/how-to-paste-data-in-columns-and-rows-in-this-way/61236813#61236813) but here is shapes(Group of shapes - picture) instead of data

**Expecting Output As subject to 3 conditions**
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub PrintLabels()
   Dim LabelsToSkip As Integer
   Dim LabelsPerRow As Integer
   Dim RowsPerPage As Integer
   Dim shdata As Worksheet
   Dim shgenerate As Worksheet
   Dim shDesignFormat As Worksheet
   Dim curRow As Long
   Dim curCol As Long
   Dim RowsPerPageCount As Long
   Dim r As Long
   Dim r2 As Long
   Dim Top As Single
   Dim Left As Single
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim shp As Shape


   Set shdata = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
   Set shgenerate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LabelGenerate")
   Set shDesignFormat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LabelDesignFormatBeforePrint")

   shgenerate.UsedRange.ClearContents

LabelsToSkip = 1
LabelsPerRow = 3
RowsPerPage = 8

   curRow = 1
   curCol = 1
   RowsPerPageCount = 1

   '.Top = myShape.Height + 10 '10 is the Vertical gap b/w label
   '.Left = myShape.Left + 10 '10 is the Horizontal gap b/w label

   Left = 0
   Top = 0


   For r = 2 To shdata.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   i = 1
      '======== Copy Shape from Data Sheet============
      shdata.Cells(r, "A").Copy shDesignFormat.Range("B3") 'pasting shape to design sheet before print (to format)

      For r2 = 1 To shdata.Cells(r, "B").Value
         '=====Paste to Generate Sheet ====
    For Each shp In shgenerate.Shapes
        If shp.Top > Top Then
            Top = shp.Top + 10 '10 is the Vertical gap b/w label
            Left = shp.Left + 10 '10 is the Horizontal gap b/w label
        End If
    Next

    Set shp = shDesignFormat.Shapes("Rectangle" & i)

    shp.Copy

    shgenerate.Paste

    With Selection
        .Top = Top
        .Left = Left
    End With

      Next r2
      i = i + 1

   Next r

   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you've been here long enough to know that you should ask a specific question. What is the problem with the code you have posted? Consider creating an [mcve] if you have a complex set up.

Comment: @SJR thanks for coming forward to help. the issue is small but I included more details to be easy for you to understand the problem. I want to print shapes (as labels) in columns and row format (ex 3*8) with respect to 3 conditions mentioned in question above. independent of cell position. Thanks

Comment: @SJR please check I have added more details.

Comment: Yes I think I understand what you want, but what is the problem with your current code? Does it error or does it run but not do what you want? If the latter, please provide details.

Comment: I am not able to understand how do I code with the above 3 conditions. I just gave it a startup with above codes. I need your support with this complex part. here is a similar post code for userfrom pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000484/can-you-tweak-these-codes-for-userform-make-it-small-and-efficient

Comment: I'll see if I can mock up a simple example which you can perhaps adapt.

Comment: @SJR Thanks for your assurance. I 'll wait.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford please, I need your help with this. you always understood my needs and provided perfect code. Kind request.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline approach.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, sh As Shape, shCopy As Shape, i As Long, nCol As Long
Dim nLeft As Long, nTop As Long, nRow As Long, j As Long, ctr As Long

nCol = 3: nTop = 10: nLeft = 10

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each sh In Worksheets("Output").Shapes
    sh.Delete
Next sh

For Each r In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each sh In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        If Not Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, r.Offset(, -1)) Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next sh
    For i = 1 To r.Value
        ctr = ctr + 1
        sh.Copy
        With Worksheets("Output")
            .PasteSpecial
            Set shCopy = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
            If ctr Mod nCol = 1 Then
                j = 0
                nRow = nRow + 1
            End If
            shCopy.Top = (nTop * nRow) + (shCopy.Height * (nRow - 1))
            shCopy.Left = j * (shCopy.Width + nLeft)
            j = j + 1
        End With
    Next i
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: looks cool. Thanks. what about conditions ? is it a working solution?

Comment: Can you Please Add the above three conditions to your answer. like starting blanks, no of shape per row, No of row per page

Comment: Can you clarify the first? The second is denoted by the variable `nCol`. Might leave the third to you ....

Comment: can you please define rest also for me. as my main reason for question to post was this only. Thanks.

Comment: FIrst condition is no. of the label to skip. suppose in place of shape I need blank space equal to shape size in place of shape. I hope it's clear. Thanks.

Comment: The idea of SO is not that you present a list of requirements and someone codes the whole project for you, it is that you make some effort yourself and post a specific question if and when you get stuck. Break this down into its constituent parts and start there.

Comment: I already made by best effort above. and after that, I open thread. please don't take it wrong.

Comment: OK in that case I think you should post each condition as a separate question. You don't have to accept my answer if it hasn't helped you, but you might want to link either to this or Brian's previous answer as that certainly does appear to have helped.

Comment: And on the "skipping " requirement, how is the size of the gap determined? Are all your shapes always the same size? Add these details to a new question.

Comment: yes, you said right. it always goes with the same size.*(there will be blank space in place of shape)  You want me to create a new question ?.your above answer already do my 90% requirement except for the conditions part.